# Upload Videos To FriendlyPix Application

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I changed the storage. rules file from:

```
// Returns true if the uploaded file is an image and its size is below 
the given number of MB.

function isImageBelowMaxSize(maxSizeMB) {
  return request.resource.size < maxSizeMB * 1024 * 1024
      && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
}

// Returns true if the user that initiated the request is an admin.
function isAdmin() {
  return request.auth.token != null && request.auth.token.admin == true;
}

// Returns true if the resource is being deleted.
function isResourceBeingDeleted() {
  return request.resource == null;
}

// Returns true if the user is the owner of the file.
function isOwner(uid) {
  return request.auth.uid == uid;
}

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{userId}/thumb/{postId}/{fileName} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if isAdmin() || isOwner(userId) && 
(isResourceBeingDeleted() || isImageBelowMaxSize(1));
    }
    match /{userId}/full/{postId}/{fileName} {
       allow read;
      allow write: if isAdmin() || isOwner(userId) && 
 (isResourceBeingDeleted() || isImageBelowMaxSize(5));
    }
   }
 }
```

to :

```
  service firebase.storage {
   match /b/rohanathavle-9b77f.appspot.com/o {
     match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
} .
```

I also changed the index.html to include the MIME type for videos:

```
<input id="fp-mediacapture" type="file" accept="image/* video/*" 
capture="camera">
```

Some changes are required in Uploader.js as suggested by the author of the GitHub link that I have posted. But none of those changes has worked out. All the changes that I made are to changes image.* to video.* i.e. allow the code to accept videos. But none of those changes is doing what I want.

Comment: I suggest you show the specific, relevant code you're working with, and the changes you've already attempted in order to make this work the way you want.

Comment: I changed the storage.rules file from :

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with `Uploader.js`.